# List of equations and related meaning - align environment

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to write a centered list of equations with the related meaning on their right side.
I'm using `{align*}` to do the job, but I get several errors when I try to compile the document.
Here the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools} %which includes also amsmath package 

\begin{document}
     \begin{align*}

        &\textbf{r} = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}        \quad  && \text{radius vector}\\
        &\textbf{v} = v_x\hat{i} + v_y\hat{j} + v_z\hat{k}  \quad  && \text{velocity vector}\\
        &\textbf{g} = -g\hat{k}                             \quad  && \text{gravity acceleration}\\
        &\hat{u}    = u_x + u_y + u_z                       \quad  && \text{unit thrust vector} 

      \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The type of errors I'm dealing with are:

> Misplaced alignment tab character &

and

> \hat allowed only in math mode

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks @campa to suggest me the error. I'm having another alignment-related issue. I would like to reduce the space between equations and the corresponding text on each line. Here the actual result:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Never leave blank lines in display math environments.

Comment: Thank you @campa, I totally ignored this syntax rule. I will keep it in mind. I'm going to update the first post, because another doubt has emerged.

Comment: Additionally don't use textbf in math mode, use mathbf or even bm from the bm package

Comment: I would align on the = instead, and the quad does nothing here, especially since align auto adds spacing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions and observations. (The first three have already been made in the comments section above.)

- don't allow all-blank lines in a display-math environment
- use `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`, for math material
- align the material in the math block on the `=` symbols
- write `\hat{\imath}` and `\hat{\jmath}`, not `\hat{i}` and `\hat{j}`, as having both a "dot" and a "hat" above `i` and `j` doesn't look good
- use an `alignat*` rather than an `align*` environment, in order to better control the horizontal distance between the math block on the left and the text block on the right
- insert a `\vphantom{\hat{k}}` directive in the final line to equalize the line spacing across all four rows. (Alternatively, change the instances of `\hat{k}` in rows 2 and 3 to `\smash{\hat{k}}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'alignat*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbf{r} &= x\hat{\imath} + y\hat{\jmath} + z\hat{k}  
   &&       \text{radius vector} \\
\mathbf{v} &= v_x\hat{\imath} + v_y\hat{\jmath} + v_z\hat{k}  
   &\qquad& \text{velocity vector} \\
\mathbf{g} &= -g\hat{k}
   &&       \text{gravity acceleration}\\
\hat{u}    &= u_x + u_y + u_z\vphantom{\hat{k}}
   &&       \text{unit thrust vector} 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your useful suggestions. @Mico I really appreciate your helpful tips as well, I'm glad to keep learning new things and tricks about the big universe of Latex.

Comment: @Catarella - You're most welcome!